# Understand elements of the gdb core print

Tags: c, gdb

I have a core generated. /var/log/messages displays this line:

```
Jan 29 07:50:40 NetAcc-02 kernel: LR.exe[15326]: segfault at 51473861 ip 081e2dba sp 00240030 error 4 in LR.exe[8048000+34c000]
Jan 29 07:50:52 NetAcc-02 abrt[20696]: saved core dump of pid 15252 (/home/netacc/active/LR.exe) to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2015-01-29-07:50:40-15252.new/coredump (1642938368 bytes)
Jan 29 07:50:52 NetAcc-02 abrtd: Directory 'ccpp-2015-01-29-07:50:40-15252' creation detected
Jan 29 07:50:54 NetAcc-02 abrtd: Executable '/home/netacc/active/LR.exe' doesn't belong to any package
Jan 29 07:50:54 NetAcc-02 abrtd: Corrupted or bad dump /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2015-01-29-07:50:40-15252 (res:2), deleting
```

Does the last line mean that the core is corrupted? Because a bt of my corefile seems to be corrupted:

```
#0  0x081e2dba in CfaPepDecision (pBuf=0xa0d6735, pIp=0x5147384d, u2DirectFlag=1, ppepserver=0x67684e6f, paccl=0x45517377, pPepMode=0x6a31396c "") at /home/TAN/release/rel/idu-sw/pep/pep/src/pepcfa.c:498
#1  0x52367331 in ?? ()
#2  0x0a0d6735 in gProfileVsatTable ()
#3  0x5147384d in ?? ()
#4  0x75417875 in ?? ()
#5  0x38000200 in ?? ()
```

Strangely the `gProfileVsatTable` is a global array!

The address `pIp = 0x5147384d` is out of bounds in gdb.

Any inputs are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Because a bt of my corefile seems to be corrupted:

This is usually the result of analyzing the wrong binary. Invoke GDB like this:

```
gdb /home/netacc/active/LR.exe \
  /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2015-01-29-07:50:40-15252.new/coredump
```

Make sure that you have *not* updated the binary since Jan 29 07:50:52. In particular, make sure you did not rebuild the binary with different options after the crash.

Comment: Hello Employed Russian! :)

The binary has not been updated. This is on a production system and not on a development system. I checked the the /var/spoo/abrt/ccp but there was no file before. Didnt Linux delete it as it says in the log file:

`Jan 29 07:50:54 NetAcc-02 abrtd: Corrupted or bad dump /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2015-01-29-07:50:40-15252 (res:2), deleting`